# given matrix $A$, decide if $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        2 & 3 & 2 & 2\\
        2 & 2 & 3 & 2\\
        2 & 2 & 2 & 3\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I know that the eigenvalues are 1 of geometric multiplicity = algebric multiplicity = 3, and 7 of geometric multiplicity = algebric multiplicity = 1.

The eigenvectors of 1 are $(1, 0, 0, -1),(1, 0, -1, 0),(1, -1, 0, 0)$ and of 7 is $(0, 1, 1, 1)$.

I given some matrices (each called $P$) and I need to decide if $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal.

For example:

$$P=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 6\\
        0 & -1 & 3 & -3\\
        2 & 0 & 3 & -3\\
        -2 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

How do I check it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$P$ will diagonalize $A$ if the columns of $P$ are eigenvectors of $A$. It looks like the 3rd column of $P$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue 7, so then you just need to see if the other three columns span the eigenspace for the eigenvalue 1.